# Rebuilding libraries in opencv

Tags: opencv

How do I rebuild a single library in opencv without having to rebuild all of opencv ? 
For example, if I want to rebuild the stitching library how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done.

Comment: Why would you want to re build only one? to do it you will need to create a cmake/makefile manually. And also, if you rebuild only one file because you did some changes, then you should build all the file that depend on such file. Still I wouldn't recommend it.... it is better to build all. Also if you only change one file the make command won't re build all just that file and the files that depend on it

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows? Linux?